# can't get the SVG to my react component getting an error

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm trying to add a SVG file but I'm getting an error tat says:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

[eslint] 
src/svg/banner.jsx
  Line 15:2:  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? (15:2)
```

this is the svg:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle
      cx="50"
      cy="50"
      r="40"
      stroke="blue"
      fill="lightblue"
    />
  </svg>
  
  
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="1921.641"
    height="170.5"
    viewBox="0 0 1921.641 170.5"
  >
    <defs>
      <linearGradient
        id="linear-gradient"
        x1="-0.038"
        y1="-1.902"
        x2="1.1"
        y2="2.41"
        gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
      >
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#4040be" />
        <stop offset="0.36" stop-color="#4e67eb" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#31c3ac" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path
      id="Path_30"
      data-name="Path 30"
      d="M0,0H1921.641V170.5H0Z"
      opacity="0.8"
      fill="url(#linear-gradient)"
    />
  </svg>
```

I'm trying to import it like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "../svg/banner.svg";
```

I've also tried to import it like this:

```
import banner from "../svg/banner.svg";
```

but it isn't working... any ideas?

using react and chakra UI

Answer (score 1):

create js file export individual SVG data import file inside {} brace and inside importing an SVG file return SVG looks like

```js
//This is my allsvg.js file
export const calender = <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-calendar" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM1 4v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4H1z" />
</svg>
//This is where i will import svg file
import { calender } = require("./Media/AllSvg");
return (<div>{calender}</div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want set the SVG as a react component, you should return one element. ( You can use react Fragment for that `<> /* ...HTML code */ </>`)

```js
export default function Svg() {
   return (
     <>
       <svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle
      cx="50"
      cy="50"
      r="40"
      stroke="blue"
      fill="lightblue"
    />
  </svg>
  
  
    <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="1921.641"
    height="170.5"
    viewBox="0 0 1921.641 170.5"
    >
    <defs>
      <linearGradient
        id="linear-gradient"
        x1="-0.038"
        y1="-1.902"
        x2="1.1"
        y2="2.41"
        gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
      >
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#4040be" />
        <stop offset="0.36" stop-color="#4e67eb" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#31c3ac" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path
      id="Path_30"
      data-name="Path 30"
      d="M0,0H1921.641V170.5H0Z"
      opacity="0.8"
      fill="url(#linear-gradient)"
    />
  </svg>
     </>
   
   )

}
```

Comment: I tried it but getting this error: 
React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can set `throwIfNamespace: false` to bypass this warning.
<svg
   9 |         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
> 10 |         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag But  Your component it's not wrapped . You can use **Fragments** to group all  your `svg tags` without adding nodes to the DOM  try it like this :

```
<>  // shorter syntax you can use for declaring fragments
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle
      cx="50"
      cy="50"
      r="40"
      stroke="blue"
      fill="lightblue"
    />
  </svg>
  
  
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="1921.641"
    height="170.5"
    viewBox="0 0 1921.641 170.5"
  >
    <defs>
      <linearGradient
        id="linear-gradient"
        x1="-0.038"
        y1="-1.902"
        x2="1.1"
        y2="2.41"
        gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
      >
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#4040be" />
        <stop offset="0.36" stop-color="#4e67eb" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#31c3ac" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path
      id="Path_30"
      data-name="Path 30"
      d="M0,0H1921.641V170.5H0Z"
      opacity="0.8"
      fill="url(#linear-gradient)"
    />
  </svg>
</>
```